# multiple dropdowns and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 questions here for vanilla JavaScript. **I cannot use jQuery.**

**1. Create multiple dropdowns.**

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function loadTheDropdowns() {
    var oTxt;
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        var oEle = document.createElement('option');
        if (i == 0) {
            oTxt = document.createTextNode("select your tenure");
            oEle.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            oEle.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
            oEle.appendChild(oTxt);
        } else {
            oTxt = document.createTextNode(i);
            oEle.appendChild(oTxt);
        }
        document.getElementById('compTenure').appendChild(oEle);
        document.getElementById('posTenure').appendChild(oEle);
    }
}
```

In my HTML I have it as:

```
<body onload="loadTheDropdowns()">
    How many years you worked on this company
    <select name="Input" id="compTenure">
    </select>
    <br />
    How many years you worked on your current position
    <select name="Input" id="posTenure">
    </select>
</body>
```

When I run this, none of the dropdowns are loaded.

**How can I load the dropdown?**

---

**2. Validating radio buttons.**

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>I was trained adequetly for my current position *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am skillfull enough to fulfill my responsibility *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I have enough time to fulfill all my responsibility *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I have required to work a proper number of hours *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I find my current position secure *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I think my work is appritiate enough *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

I'm using this function to validate.

```
function validate() {
    if (!document.getElementsByName('cprb1')[0].checked ||
        !document.getElementsByName('cprb2')[0].checked || 
        !document.getElementsByName('cprb3')[0].checked || 
        !document.getElementsByName('cprb4')[0].checked || 
        !document.getElementsByName('cprb5')[0].checked || 
        !document.getElementsByName('cprb6')[0].checked) {
            alert("RB not check");
        }
    }
```

The issue is that it is only checking if the first radio button is checked. If I remove that `[0]`, it is alerting `RB not check`, even though I'm selecting the radio buttons.

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Post a working snippet

Comment: @ShadowFiend my bad, sorry, I've this in my code, a typo, missed adding it to the question, updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First answer : it's a variable reference problem. You have to make two different `oEle` element or using `oEle.cloneNode();` like

```
document.getElementById('posTenure').appendChild(oEle.cloneNode(true));
```

Second answer : you take only the first checkbox element, you have to loop them like :

```
function check(name) {
     var cprb = document.getElementsByName(name);
     for(var i = 0; i<cprb.length;i++){
        if(cprb[i].checked)
          return true;
     }
}
function validate() {
     if(!check('cprb1') && !check('cprb2') && !check('cprb3') && !check('cprb4') && !check('cprb5') && !check('cprb6'))
         alert("RB not check");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For first question, after you append the `option` element to first dropdown, you can create a clone of the option element and append to second dropdown. If you do not clone, then the option element is always appended to second dropdown leaving the first dropdown empty.

```js
window.onload = function () { loadTheDropdowns(); }
function loadTheDropdowns() {
    var oTxt;
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
        var oEle = document.createElement('option');
        if (i == 0) {
            oTxt = document.createTextNode("select your tenure");
            oEle.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            oEle.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
            oEle.appendChild(oTxt);
        } else {
            oTxt = document.createTextNode(i);
            oEle.appendChild(oTxt);
        }

        document.getElementById('compTenure').appendChild(oEle);
        var oPos = oEle.cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById('posTenure').appendChild(oPos);
    }
}
```

```html
How many years you worked on this company
<select name="Input" id="compTenure"></select>
<br/>
<br /> How many years you worked on your current position
<select name="Input" id="posTenure"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

your Radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_button" value="radio_button_value">
```

now you can access any radio button checked through below code with name property

```
var check_radio = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio_button"]:checked')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 5 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.