# enable textbox based on the radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html

This is an extension of my previous question available at [multiple dropdowns and radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274369/multiple-dropdowns-and-radio-buttons/46274543#46274543).

Here is my question, I'm able to select all the radio buttons and validate them, but here is the tricky part, there is this `comments` text area, and from radio buttons set, if any one matches to `neutral` (`v3`), then the comments box should have a text as `hello`, if any of the radio buttons matches `Strongly Disagree`, the comments box should have any text entered. here is my updated HTML.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>I was trained adequetly for my current position *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb1" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I am skillfull enough to fulfill my responsibility *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb2" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I have enough time to fulfill all my responsibility *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb3" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I have required to work a proper number of hours *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb4" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I find my current position secure *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb5" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>I think my work is appritiate enough *</td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V1" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V2" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V3" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V4" /></td>
        <td><input name="cprb6" type="radio" value="V5" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
Comments
<textarea name="comment" id="cprComment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

and here is my javascript

```
function validate() {
if (getTheValueForDisagree('cprb1') || getTheValueForDisagree('cprb2') || getTheValueForDisagree('cprb3') || getTheValueForDisagree('cprb4') || getTheValueForDisagree('cprb5') || getTheValueForDisagree('cprb6')) {
                if (document.getElementById("cprComment").value === "") {
                    alert("Comments for How do you feel about your current position? is required");
                    return false;
                }

            }

            if (getTheValueForNeutral('cprb1') || getTheValueForNeutral('cprb2') || getTheValueForNeutral('cprb3') || getTheValueForNeutral('cprb4') || getTheValueForNeutral('cprb5') || getTheValueForNeutral('cprb6')) {
                if (document.getElementById("cprComment").value === "") {
                    document.getElementById("cprComment").value = "Hello";
                }
            }

}
function getTheValueForDisagree(name) {
            var cprb = document.getElementsByName(name);

            for (var i = 0; i < cprb.length; i++) {
                if (cprb[i].value === "V5") {
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }

        function getTheValueForNeutral(name) {
            var cprb = document.getElementsByName(name);
            for (var i = 0; i < cprb.length; i++) {
                if (cprb[i].value === "V3")
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

and here in case where a `neutral` and `strongly disagree` are selected, the comment should be filled based on the order.for eg. if the `strongly disagree` is selected first and in the next there is `Neutral` next, then there should be text in the text area, if it is in the otherway `Hello` should be in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
    function validate() {
        var gr1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb1"]:checked').value;
        var gr2 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb2"]:checked').value;
        var gr3 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb3"]:checked').value;
        var gr4 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb4"]:checked').value;
        var gr5 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb5"]:checked').value;
        var gr6 = document.querySelector('input[name = "cprb6"]:checked').value;

        console.log(gr1 + "  " + gr2 + " " + gr3 + "  " + gr4 + " " + gr5 + "  " + gr6);

        if (gr1 === "V5" || gr2 === "V5" || gr3 === "V5" || gr4 === "V5" || gr5 === "V5" || gr6 === "V5" ) {
            if (document.getElementById("cprComment").value === "") {
                alert("Comments for How do you feel about your current position? is required");
                return false;
            }

        }

        if (gr1 === "V3" || gr2 === "V3" || gr3 === "V3" || gr4 === "V3" || gr5 === "V3" || gr6 === "V3" ) {
            if (document.getElementById("cprComment").value === "") {
                document.getElementById("cprComment").value = "Hello";
            }
        }

    }
```